# Join and query Django models on non-primary-key relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got two models that are logically related through a field that is not the primary key. Is it possible to query them (ex, `select_related(…)`) without introducing a `ForeignKey` column?

For example, consider the contrived models:

```
class LogEntry(Model):
    source_name = CharField(…)
    log_message = CharField(…)

class LogSource(Model):
    name = CharField(…)
    domain = CharField(…)
```

I would like to be able to query `LogEntry`, joining in and filtering on the related `LogSource` (ex, so I can access `log_entry.source` without additional queries):

```
LogEntry.objects
    .select_related(
        source=Join(LogSource, on="logsource.name = logentry.source_name")),
    )
    .filter(source__domain="example.com")
```

Is this possible *without introducing a ForeignKey*?

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do this by using [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra) with the `tables` option.

```
LogEntry.objects.extra(
    tables=['logsource'],
    where=['logsource.name=logentry.source_name',
           'logsource_domain="example.com"',
           ]
)
```

Another option is to change `source_name` to a foreign key, but specify the [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-column) and [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) arguments to use the existing columns. I know that you said that you didn't want to add a foreign key, but it might be acceptable because it only changes the models, not the columns in the database tables. However, be aware that Django might want to create a foreign key constraint. One hack would be to fake that migration so that the constraint isn't created in the db.

```
class LogEntry(Model):
    source_name = models.ForeignKey(db_column=source_name', to_field='name')
```

`log_entry.source_name` would then be the `LogSource` instance, and `log_entry.source_name_id` would be the value stored in the `source_name` column. It might make sense to rename the field from `source_name` to `source` after converting to a foreign key, but that's not necessary.

Comment: Interesting… I hadn't considered using a `ForeignKey` with custom `db_column` and `to_field`… I'd have to do some fiddling to make sure that the FK constraint isn't enforced (ie, so I can insert a `LogEntry` before the corresponding `LogSource` exists).

Comment: Is there any way to convert the result of the `extra` query into an instance of `LogSource`? Or would I need to do some fiddling to take the `log_source.*` columns and create my own instance of `LogSource`?

Comment: Yes, good point, you'll need to be careful that it doesn't create any unwanted foreign key constraints, I've updated the answer above.

Comment: No, I don't think there is any way to turn the extra query into a `LogSource` instance. Another limitation, as you can see above, is that I had to move the domain filter from `filter()` into `extra()` call as well.