# Can Django ORM join on something other than pk?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, psql

From: `StartTable.objects.annotate(name=F('object_type_2__destination_table__name'))`

Django writes a query containing this automatically:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "object" T4 ON ("start_table"."object_type_2_id" = T4."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "destination_table" ON (T4."id" = "destination_table"."object_id")
```

Is there a way to have Django make this more efficient by writing this instead?:

```
JOIN destination_table ON destination_table.object_id = start_table.object_type_2_id
```

Some context to keep in mind; the `start_table` has several foreign key fields that all refer to the same `object` table, but for different reasons, which is why I've given `object_type_2_id` as the column name.

Comment: Could you please provide ORM code that you're using? But yes, you can join models on other fields instead of pk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735717/join-and-query-django-models-on-non-primary-key-relationship

Comment: Thank you for your response! Will update my question in a moment.

Comment: Hm, it isn't entirely clear how to go about referencing the table after the fact... and it also looks like I wont be able to filter after using extra? I'll have to experiment with the other option...

Comment: Just want to mention that `extra` should be avoided,  it is going to be deprecated in some time and have a lot of limitations. I.e. it won't deal correctly with tables aliases which happens frequently when using ORM.  Actually you shouldn't refer to your table as 'start_table',  because it can be aliased under some conditions. I thinks the optimization you are looking for is quite premature.  Have you run some benchmarks and confirmed the speed issue?

Comment: It's not actually called start_table, I'm just aliasing the names for privacy/clarity reasons. And it isn't premature, there is a significant performance gain in my case to skip the unnecessary join (since several of them are being done for a tremendous number of rows in my annotations). I want to keep it in Django tho, since I expect to filter on the results afterward. I don't want to have to write sql for this entire part of the app.

Comment: Yeah,  about aliasing,  I think we are misunderstanding each other. I mean ORM internal aliases for SQL generated as 'T4'  which   you can see in your query. And if you use `extra`,  you would have to put your table 
 name directly in that select string,  which will break if you want to perform some more advanced operations on this query. Unfortunately,  there is no direct way to add custom join. If it is okay for your DB schema,  try to make use of Subquery.  It will add nested SELECT clause which can be pretty slow,  but some database  will promote it into JOIN internally.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions Here is the documentation about this.

Comment: I've attempted Subquery in other cases, and it's typically very expensive. I can try it here and see if postgres will be smart about it, otherwise I'll have to find some other kind of work around.